# Can't connect Macbook to VPS through SSH after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: network, ssh

I have just upgraded my VPS from Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 22.04. After the upgrade, my server has OpenSSH 8.9.

After the upgrade, I can't access my VPS anymore through SSH using my Macbook Pro.

I am using a Macbook Pro mid-2014 with OSX 10.10.5, and OpenSSH 6.2.

I also have another local machine with Ubuntu 18.04 and OpenSSH 7.6, with which I can still connect to the VPS without error.

Here is the error:

```
$ ssh -p XXX -v thibaut@XX.XX.XXX.XXX
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to XX.XX.XXX.XXX [XX.XX.XXX.XXX] port XXX.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/thibautvoirand/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thibautvoirand/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thibautvoirand/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/thibautvoirand/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
no hostkey alg
```

I am not sure I understand this error.

Could I fix it by updating my VPS SSH configuration?

I also intend to upgrade my Macbook Pro OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading my OS I can now successfully connect from my Macbook Pro to my VPS through SSH.

I upgraded from OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 to macOS Sierra 10.12.6. I now intend to upgrade to macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

For information, I had trouble upgrading my OS because I couldn't connect to the App Store anymore to obtain the newest OS versions. Apple support directed me to [this link](https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/HT211683) to obtain newer OS versions. They advised me to upgrade first to Sierra, and then to Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenSSH Version 8.8 SHA-1 is deprecated. Generate a new key pair with an appropriate cryptographic algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. I have generated a key pair on the Macbook Pro, I still get the same error. I have also generated another key pair on my Linux machine, and can access the VPS from the Linux machine using this other key pair.

Comment: Forgot to mention in my previous comment: the key pairs I generated use the RSA algorithm